# PHP interpret a 4 byte binary string as an unsigned big endian integer

Tags: php, endianness

I am trying to interpret a binary string as an unsigned big endian integer, as her instructions here: http://mimesniff.spec.whatwg.org/#matches-the-signature-for-mp4 (point 4)

I'm not quite sure what I need to do here, but here are my attempts:

```
// ONE
$box_size   = substr( $sequence, 0, 4 );
$box_size   = pack( 'C*', $box_size[0], $box_size[1], $box_size[2], $box_size[3] );
$box_size   = unpack( 'N*', $box_size );

// TWO
$box_size   = substr( $sequence, 0, 4 );
$box_size   = array_map( 'ord', str_split( $box_size ) );

// THREE
$box_size   = substr( $sequence, 0, 4 );
$box_size   = bindec( $box_size );

// FOUR
$box_size   = substr( $sequence, 0, 4);
$box_size   = (int) $box_size;
```

I have had no luck, and honestly am not sure what the result should even be.. Does anyone understand this? I think I might be on the right track with pack and unpack.

Comment: Just `unpack('N', $string)` should do just fine.

Comment: Wow... That was very easy. The difference between pack and unpack confuses me.. But this seems to have worked a treat. Thanks deceze!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll go ahead and post the comment as an answer then...

To *unpack* a "compact" bit representation of something into a native type, just use `unpack` with the right parameters to denote the type of bits you're unpacking. In your case:

```
$unpacked = unpack('N', $unsignedBigEndianInteger);
$int = $unpacked[1];
```

This makes PHP read the byte stream assuming it represents an unsigned big endian long and convert it into a PHP native integer.

Remember:

- `pack`: "large native type" → squeeze into byte representation
- `unpack`: compact byte representation → "large native type"

Comment: Sorry, shouldn't it be $unpacked[1]; ? Thanks for that little end note :)